# How to check whether an Hive table is an external table using Spark SQL Scala API(not SQL）

Tags: apache-spark

I am using following code(Spark SQL Scala API) to check whether an Hive table is an external table ,but the `Table` API doesn't has the method to answer whether the given table is an external table.

I would ask how I could check whether an Hive table is an external table 
 using Spark SQL Scala API(not SQL）

The code is:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("SparkSQLTest1-1").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
val table = spark.catalog.getTable("db1.t1")
```

Comment: I think you can use "describe formatted table_name" statement in Spark SQL and parse the output. The output contains field Table Type which can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use catalog API:

```
sparkSession.catalog.listTables("db1")
.where($"name"==="t1")
.select($"tableType")
.as[String]
.first
```

`MANAGED` means hive-managed table, `EXTERNAL` will be hive external table

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve this information directly from `desc formated`:

```
scala> spark.sql("desc formatted db1.t1")
    .filter($"col_name" === "Type")
    .select("data_type")
    .as[String]
    .head
res11: String = EXTERNAL
```

Comment: But this is also based on SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can use show create table command. And determine table type from the result.

```
spark.sql("show create table db1.t1").show(false)
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to use sql and parse result. I would like to use spark scala API